# Allow only certain words in OCR

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract

I use the `ocr()` function from the `tesseract` package and my input images have a relatively little pool of words that appear on them. At the same time the images are not that great which makes text recognition bad.

So I guess the processing would be much better if I could tell the function what those words on the images are and let `ocr()` look for those words. Is there such an argument or function or some hacky solution to this?

My expected code is like this:

```
text <- tesseract::ocr(img) |> magic_stuff_i_am_asking_for(accepted_words= words_pool)
all(unlist(strsplit(text1, "\\s|\n")) %in% words_pool)
TRUE # Meaning ocr() was looking for only my words..
```

If this is too strict: Is there a way to tell `ocr()` to prefer words in `words_pool`? Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/main/doc/tesseract.1.asc#config-files-and-augmenting-with-user-data

Comment: @M-- That is seemingly the right hint but I can't figure out how to do it (I know only R). More precisely, I don't understand how to create those three described files and how to pass the word bazaar into a CONFIGFILE (is it an argument in the ocr function?).

Comment: The comment does not specifically refer to the R pkg. It is about tesseract in general - you can install it from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract#installing-tesseract and run it via command line. Maybe this clears things up for you. The R pkg basically is an interface (via R code) to this software. You do not write bazaar into a CONFIGFILE - the predefined config file is called bazaar. But you can easily create your own - there are just four paramters set in bazaar config. In R you can set them like in my answer under options tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = "hp3"))

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you at least a little bit:

Tesseract has a lot of configuration options to choose from. Use this command to look at the plentiful options:

```
tesseract_params('word')
```

As you can see, you can use the String to filter for specific parameter options ... really helpful, because there are so many.

I also couldn't get the `bazaar` config mentioned in the link from Ingo running (also seen some posts, that this might not work any more at all on the current version)

What might help is `tessedit_char_whitelist` - which doesn't reduce the scope to specific words, but it only allows certain characters.

Here an example:

```
# Create a image to have some text
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) 
ggsave("test.png",p, "png")
```

[image]

If I run tesseract now without changing the param options on the image

```
library("tesseract")
ocr(image ="test.png", engine = tesseract("eng"))
ocr_data(image ="test.png")
```

I get quite high confidence values for a lot of "words"

[image]

Let's say I know I am only interested in hp and threes, I could do the following:

```
wl <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = "hp3"))
ocr("test.png", engine = wl)
ocr_data(image ="test.png", engine = wl)
```

So I create a tesseract engine with specific control parameters and use this within the ocr call.

[image]

Now it found exactly all three threes and the hp.

By the way, also take a look at `ocr_data()`, which I used here. It gives you a  data frame with a confidence rate and bounding box for each word in the text.

I don't think this is exactly what you were searching for, but maybe it helps.

In general it should also somehow be possible to train with your own data ... you'll also find tutorials on this online ... but I don't really know to what extend you are limited by the R package / API implementation.